# Not sure why I can't deserialize an HTTP JSON object response

Tags: apex, json

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I'm trying to quickly deserialize HTTP JSON output into a string to search thru and pull specific keys to see if they meet a certain condition. My code doesn't come back with any errors, but when I go to execute it, I receive the following notice:

> **Execute Anonymous Error** 
>   Line: 15, Column: 1 System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set

My Apex code is as follows:

```
public static List<String> listGroups(){ 
    HTTPRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setMethod('GET');
    request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    request.setEndpoint('callout:Website1/');
    HTTPResponse response = new Http().send(request);
    String http_response = response.getBody();
    List<String> data = (List<String>) JSON.deserialize(http_response, List<String>.class);
    return data;
}
```

And here is the function call I'm performing elsewhere in my Apex program:

```
List<String> output=listGroups();
```

JSON output example:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')/drive/root/children",
    "value": [
        {
            "createdDateTime": "2018-06-04T20:30:42Z",
            "eTag": "\"{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx},1\"",
            "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-06-04T20:30:42Z",
            "name": "Jack's files",
            "webUrl": "https://example.com/sites/xxxxx/",
            "cTag": "\"c:{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx},0\"",
            "size": 6566266651,
            "createdBy": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "MBravo@example.com",
                    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "displayName": "Mike Bravo"
                }
            },
            "lastModifiedBy": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "MBravo@example.com",
                    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "displayName": "Mike Bravo"
                }
            },
            "parentReference": {
                "driveId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "driveType": "documentLibrary",
                "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "path": "/drive/root:"
            },
            "fileSystemInfo": {
                "createdDateTime": "2018-06-04T20:30:42Z",
                "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-06-04T20:30:42Z"
            },
            "folder": {
                "childCount": 1
            }
        },
....}]
}
```

Comment: Can you dump the actual value of http_response here? Seems that JSON string in wrong indeed.

Comment: What does the JSON content look like? Most likely there's another layer wrapping the content you want. (`{ "response": [ ... content ...] }`)

Comment: It's hard to know whether your code or the JSON is at fault without seeing the JSON itself. Please edit your question to include the JSON.

Comment: As requested, see above

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By passing `List<String>.class` to the `JSON.deserialize` function, you're telling it to look for a list. A list in JSON should start with `[`. The error message is telling you that it looked for `[`, but couldn't find it.

Check exactly what the web service is returning by outputting `http_response` to the debug log.

Some services return a single object instead of a list with one item if there's only one item. Which is annoying, but can be handled if you're looking for it.

**Edit**

Now that you've elaborated on what you're trying to do, I'd say you need to parse the whole thing using the untyped parser like this:

```
Map<String, Object> topLevel = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(http_response);
List<Object> values = (List<Object>)topLevel.get('value');
System.debug(values);
```

I know you said you don't need to parse all of it, but this is by far the most concise approach. I guess you could serialise back to JSON again once you've found the right part of the tree. But, TBH, text-searching JSON doesn't sound like a great idea in the first place.